# Getting Quotes from eTrade API in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, etrade-api

I'm trying to get quotes from the etrade API. I'm able to list accounts, get transactions, but not get quotes. I've tried removing the accounts and transactions api calls but it makes no difference. I get an "oauth_problem=signature_invalid" response. Any ideas what I need to do differently?

```
from rauth import OAuth1Service
import webbrowser
import hmac

# required for google sheets
# from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request


class ETradeManager():
    def __init__(self):
        session = None
        service = None

    def connect_to_etrade(self):
        self.service = OAuth1Service(
            name='etrade',
            consumer_key='',
            consumer_secret='',
            request_token_url='https://apisb.etrade.com/oauth/request_token',
            access_token_url='https://apisb.etrade.com/oauth/access_token',
            authorize_url='https://us.etrade.com/e/t/etws/authorize?key={}&token={}',
            base_url='https://etsw.etrade.com')

        oauth_token, oauth_token_secret = self.service.get_request_token(params=
                                                                    {'oauth_callback': 'oob',
                                                                     'format': 'json'})

        auth_url = self.service.authorize_url.format(self.service.consumer_key, oauth_token)
        webbrowser.open(auth_url)
        verifier = input('Please input the verifier: ')
        print("Attempting to get session")
        self.session = self.service.get_auth_session(oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, params={'oauth_verifier': verifier})

        url = 'https://apisb.etrade.com/v1/accounts/list'
        resp = self.session.get(url, params={'format': 'json'})
        accountid = ""
        print(resp.text)
        trans_url_template = "https://apisb.etrade.com/v1/accounts/{}/transactions"
        trans_url = trans_url_template.format(accountid)
        resp = self.session.get(trans_url, params={'format': 'json'})
        f = open("trans.xml", "w")
        f.write(resp.text)
        # key = self.service.consumer_secret + \
        #       '&' + \
        #       oauth_token_secret
        # hashed = hmac.new(key.encode(), base_string.encode(), sha1)

    # def get_quote(self):
        quote_url_template = "https://apisb.etrade.com/v1/market/quote/{}"
        quote_url = quote_url_template.format("TSLA")
        resp = self.session.get(quote_url_template, params={'format': 'json'})
        f = open("quote.xml", "w")
        f.write(resp.text)




trade_manager = ETradeManager()
    

trade_manager.connect_to_etrade()
# trade_manager.get_quote()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured this out but you had a typo here:

```
    resp = self.session.get(quote_url_template, params={'format': 'json'})
```

Should be using quote_url, not quote_url_template

Answer (score 0):

here is how to get a FULL STOCK QUOTE from the E*TRADE API. I highly recommend FIRST using the AUTH from rauth import OAuth1Service in the "etrade_python_client.py" file and not trying to rewrite everything in terms of the login AUTHORIZATION details.  **However after you login you can get a FULL QUOTE using this python 3 code.**

```
    symbols = input("\nPlease enter Stock Symbol: ")

    # URL for the API endpoint
    url = self.base_url + "/v1/market/quote/" + symbols + ".json"

    # Make API call for GET request
    response = self.session.get(url)
    logger.debug("Request Header: %s", response.request.headers)

    if response is not None and response.status_code == 200:

        parsed = json.loads(response.text)
        logger.debug("Response Body: %s", json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True))

        # Handle and parse response
        print("")
        data = response.json()
        if data is not None and "QuoteResponse" in data and "QuoteData" in data["QuoteResponse"]:
            for quote in data["QuoteResponse"]["QuoteData"]:
                for ticker in quote["All"]:
                    print(f"{ticker} : {quote['All'][ticker]}")
```

**output should look sometime like this!**

> Please enter Stock Symbol: pbr
>
> adjustedFlag : False ask : 14.75 askSize : 1000 askTime : 19:58:50 EDT
> 03-14-2024 bid : 14.69 bidExchange :  bidSize : 1000 bidTime :
> 19:58:50 EDT 03-14-2024 changeClose : -0.09 changeClosePercentage :
> -0.61 companyName : PETROLEO BRASILEIRO SA PETROBR SPONSORED ADR daysToExpiration : 0 dirLast : 2 dividend : 0.1486 eps : 4.7883
> estEarnings : 3.417 exDividendDate : 1700701244 high : 15.02 high52 :
> 17.91 lastTrade : 14.72 low : 14.62 low52 : 9.56 open : 15.0 openInterest : 0 optionStyle :  optionUnderlier :  previousClose :
> 14.81 previousDayVolume : 24150311 primaryExchange : NYSE symbolDescription : PETROLEO BRASILEIRO SA PETROBR SPONSORED ADR
> totalVolume : 26314048 upc : 0 cashDeliverable : 0 marketCap :
> 54776461440.0 sharesOutstanding : 3721227000 nextEarningDate :  beta : 0.72 yield : 17.3329 declaredDividend : 0.1486 dividendPayableDate : 1709082044 pe : 3.755 week52LowDate : 1679702444 week52HiDate :
> 1709082044 intrinsicValue : 0.0 timePremium : 0.0 optionMultiplier :
> 0.0 contractSize : 0.0 expirationDate : 0 timeOfLastTrade : 1710447000 averageVolume : 30514176 ExtendedHourQuoteDetail : {'lastPrice':
> 14.72, 'change': -0.09, 'percentChange': -0.61, 'bid': 14.69, 'bidSize': 1000, 'ask': 14.75, 'askSize': 1000, 'volume': 26314048,
> 'timeOfLastTrade': 1710460730, 'timeZone': 'EST', 'quoteStatus':
> 'EH_CLOSED'}